# Has anyone used Intelligent search's software to verify correct address?

Tags: street-address

We are planning to use Correct address software from [intelligentsearch](http://www.intelligentsearch.com/)

Has anyone used their software ? Any feedback on performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe's right. I work for a company called SmartyStreets which does address verification. I've noticed in my experience that a lot of CASS-Certified vendors don't have visible prices and even though they're business-to-business, for some reason they make it an obscure experience.
(UPDATE: They do have their prices... kind of buried: http://www.intelligentsearch.com/Hosted/Pricing/pricing.aspx) Anyway, you'll need a CASS-Certified service to get the results you want.

Do you have a list of addresses ready to clean and verify or do you want to verify addresses as they are entered? Either way, there are [list scrubbing services](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/CASS-Certified-Scrubbing/) and [APIs](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/) for both task.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that particular company, but we do address validation where I work.  We actually licensed the AMS system directly from the USPS and built our own web service around it.  I suspect anyone that's offering you a web service licensed the software and so the data should be the same.  For us it was significantly cheaper to build and maintain our own web service, which just sits on top of AMS.  Be forewarned though the software is a C library and since we use C# we had to write a lot of interop to call it.